# Java : Opening client socket

Tags: java, sockets, websocket

I work on a java application.
I got a java socket server mapped with a @ServerEndpoint("/wsock")

Form my javascript code I access the WebSocket from this URL : 
ws://192.9.200.73:8084/socketserver/wsock

I want now access to this socket from my java code. But how can I specify the address "socketserver/wsock" ? I've tried something but I got every time an error message.

This is my test :

```
Socket s = new Socket("localhost/socketserver/wsock", 8084);
```

But it doesn't work, I got everytime an error message: ".UnknownHostException: localhost/socketserver/wsock"

Any idea?

Thank's

Comment: Can you use [Tyrus framework](https://dzone.com/articles/sample-java-web-socket-client) either in a Java EE environment or as a standalone client if you're working on a Java SE environment?

Answer (score 3):

```
public static boolean pingHost(String host, int port, int timeout) {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket()) {
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false; // Either timeout or unreachable or failed DNS lookup.
    }
}
```

Try this. Its something like ping. If you get true its connected. But your server should be ready.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Unfortunately this not work, i got still an error message : "java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost/socketserver/wsock" with this call : boolean test = pingHost("localhost/quartispro-tools/wsock", 8084, 5000);

Comment: maybe you should try httpRequest to that address

Comment: It make no difference

Comment: pingHost("127.0.0.1", 8084, 5000); try this :D or pingHost("localhost", 8084, 5000);

Comment: would actually do pingHost("192.9.200.73", 8084, 5000); or pingHost("localhost", 8084, 5000);

Answer (score 0):

You use a Websocket client. You can't use a `Socket` directly for this. There is a superimposed protocol.